Debugging will be disabled for this thread in VS Code
I receive this error in VS Code after interrupting the debugger from a Jupiter notebook:
<class 'keyboardinterrupt'> raised from within the callback set in sys.settrace. debugging will be disabled for this thread (<_mainthread(mainthread, started 11352)>).

After receiving this message, I can't use the debugger anymore and I need to restart VS Code to be able to use it again.
How could I solve it?

this could be because a break in the code. Do you have raise KeyboradInterrupt in debugging? You can try adding signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal.SIG_IGN) to your code. Then restart the extension Jupyter to see if that solves the problem. You can also set the  "console": "integratedTerminal", in the launch.json file to try it.

Creating the default Python launch.json file (which included "console": "integratedTerminal") seemed to do the trick for me.

That's great, hopefully these will help you.
